# dplyr mutate inside for loop - Issue

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am performing Data Analysis and cleaning in R using tidyverse.
I have a Data Frame with 23 columns containing values 'NO','STEADY','UP' and 'down'.
I want to change all the values in these 23 columns to 0 in case of 'NO','STEADY' and 1 in other case.

What i did is, i created a list by name keys in which i have kept all my columns, After that i am using for loop, ifelse statements and mutate.

Please have a look at the code below

```
# Column names are kept in the list by name keys

keys = c('metformin', 'repaglinide', 'nateglinide', 'chlorpropamide', 'glimepiride', 
'glipizide', 'glyburide', 'pioglitazone', 'rosiglitazone', 'acarbose', 'miglitol', 
'insulin', 'glyburide-metformin', 'tolazamide', 'metformin-pioglitazone',
'metformin-rosiglitazone', 'glimepiride-pioglitazone', 'glipizide-metformin', 
'troglitazone', 'tolbutamide', 'acetohexamide')
```

After that, i used following code to get the desired result :

```
for (col in keys){
  Dataset = Dataset %>%
    mutate(col = ifelse(col %in% c('No','Steady'),0,1)) }
```

I was expecting that, it will do the changes that i require, but nothing happens after this. (NO ERROR MESSAGE AND NO DESIRED RESULT)

After that, i researched further and executed following code

```
for (col in keys){
 print(col)}
```

It gives me elements of list as characters like - "metformin"

So, i thought - may be this is the issue. Hence, i used the below code to caste the keys as symbols :

```
keys_new = sym(keys)
```

After that i again ran the same code:

```
for (col in keys_new){
   Dataset = Dataset %>%
     mutate(col = ifelse(col %in% c('No','Steady'),0,1))}
```

It gives me following Error -

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
>     'match' requires vector arguments

After all this.  I also tried to create a function to get the desired results, but that too didn't worked:

```
change = function(name){
   Dataset = Dataset %>%
      mutate(name = ifelse(name %in% c('No','Steady'),0,1),
      name = as.factor(name))
      return(Dataset)}

for (col in keys){
   change(col)}
```

This didn't perform any action. (NO ERROR MESSAGE AND NO DESIRED RESULT)

When keys_new is placed in this code:

```
for (col in keys_new){
   change(col)}
```

I got the same Error :

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
>    'match' requires vector arguments

PLEASE GUIDE

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to loop or keep track of column names. You can use `mutate_all` -

```
Dataset %>% 
  mutate_all(~ifelse(. %in% c('No','Steady'), 0, 1))
```

Another way, thanks to Rui Barradas -

```
Dataset %>% 
  mutate_all(~as.integer(!. %in% c('No','Steady')))
```

Comment: Simpler: `~as.integer(!. %in% c('No','Steady'))`

Answer (score 3):

There's a simpler way using mutate_at and case_when.

```
Dataset %>% mutate_at(keys, ~case_when(. %in% c("NO", "STEADY") ~ 0, TRUE ~ 1))
```

`mutate_at` will only mutate the columns specified in the keys variable. `case_when` then lets you replace one value by another by some condition.

Comment: Simpler: `~as.integer(!. %in% c("NO", "STEADY"))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked for me. However i will be really grateful, if you please let me know, from where i can study these functions like mutate_at in detail

Comment: @AnkurKumarChhabra Most of these functions are part of the tidyverse, and they link to some great resources on [their site](https://www.tidyverse.org/learn/). Rstudio also maintains a collection of [cheat sheets](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/) for the tidyverse that are really handy.

Answer (score 2):

This answer for using mutate through `forloop`.

I don't have your data, so i tried to make my own data, i changed the keys into a `tibble` using `enframe` then spread it into columns and used the row number as a value for each column, then check if the value is higher than 10 or not.

**To use the column name in mutate you have to use `!!` and `:=` in the mutate function**

```
df <- enframe(c('metformin', 'repaglinide', 'nateglinide', 'chlorpropamide', 'glimepiride', 
                 'glipizide', 'glyburide', 'pioglitazone', 'rosiglitazone', 'acarbose', 'miglitol', 
                 'insulin', 'glyburide-metformin', 'tolazamide', 'metformin-pioglitazone',
                 'metformin-rosiglitazone', 'glimepiride-pioglitazone', 'glipizide-metformin', 
                 'troglitazone', 'tolbutamide', 'acetohexamide')
) %>% spread(key = value,value = name)

keys = c('metformin', 'repaglinide', 'nateglinide', 'chlorpropamide', 'glimepiride', 
         'glipizide', 'glyburide', 'pioglitazone', 'rosiglitazone', 'acarbose', 'miglitol', 
         'insulin', 'glyburide-metformin', 'tolazamide', 'metformin-pioglitazone',
         'metformin-rosiglitazone', 'glimepiride-pioglitazone', 'glipizide-metformin', 
         'troglitazone', 'tolbutamide', 'acetohexamide')


for (col in keys){
        df = df %>%
                mutate(!!as.character(col) := ifelse( df[col] > 10,0,100) )
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear.................Really informative and exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @AnkurKumarChhabra please can u make it as an answer ?